# Ubuntu partitioning and installation error, due to bad HDD sector(s)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, system-installation

I have a 320GB HDD, which I have formatted, since it ran windows7 earlier. 
Now I see, that the HDD is bad in `c:`, so I concluded this because, Ubuntu gave me an error, that this drive is bad at some point during installation.

- Please guide me as how can I make partition, so that the bad sector(s) is/are not used in the installation of Ubuntu. I badly need this OS.

Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?  What does the disks's SMART heath status in the disk utility show?  If it really is failing then you really need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

When I time ago decided to install Ubuntu,

I had an error on the beginning of the installation

I then discovered that the download of the ISO file wasn't properly made.The second time I did a verification of the download and was fine , I was able to install it.

Also , make sure to choose the proper one for your pc ,32bit or 64bit.

**And btw , Ubuntu will automatically guide you on partitioning during the installation if you need it

Answer (score 0):

Run a [SMART test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) on the disk. You can do this in Linux using tools like `smartctl` (text-mode) or GSmartControl (GUI). Unfortunately, the results can be a little hard to interpret, particularly for the text-mode tools, so feel free to post back with the *complete* results if you need help interpreting them. (Post text-mode output to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), if necessary.)

If the SMART test shows that you have actual bad sectors, ***REPLACE THE DISK IMMEDIATELY!!*** Modern disks can map out a small number of bad sectors automatically, and if the number of bad sectors exceeds this built-in capacity, it indicates a serious problem with the disk. Such problems can get worse with time, often quite quickly and without further warning. Therefore, any disk that has bad sectors that are showing up at the OS level is unsafe for your data.

If the SMART test shows that the disk is in good health and has no actual bad sectors, then something else is causing your problem, and you should do some work to better identify that problem. Your initial report is a bit vague on this topic. The *precise* error message you're seeing may be important to diagnosing this problem, so providing cut-and-pasted text or screen shots of error dialog boxes is important.